# Transfer files from windows machine to remote solaris machine using python script

Tags: python

i used following code to establish connection between my local machine and the remote machine :

```
import os, sys, ftplib

nonpassive=False
remotesite= '10.88.203.21:22'
remoteuser='root'
remotepass='v-peg8!@#'
localdir= "c:\\.."
print "connecting"

connection=ftplib.FTP(remotesite)
print "successfully connected"

connection.login(remoteuser,remotepass)

if nonpassive:
    connection.set_pasv(False)
```

But its giving me following error:
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed..
can somebody plz help me out with this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the port as a separate argument, not in the way you have it in `remotesite`. Try:

```
remotesite = '10.88.203.21'
port = 22
connection = ftplib.FTP(remotesite, port)
```

See the [FTP docs](http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html#ftp-objects) for more information.

Comment: hi,  it still dint work. m getting this error:    socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machi
ne actively refused it..???

Comment: @rushi: this means that there is no server program listening at the specified endpoint (ip address + port).  One possibility is that your have the wrong port -- are you sure it's port 22?  Try the default port 21.

Comment: yeah i tried that too still giving the same error.actually m new to this thats y dont know much...cud u tell me wat cud be the possible mistake i hv made????

Answer (score 1):

If its port 22, then you are using wrong port, since most systems use 22 for SSH protocol. Assuming that 22 is normal SSH port, you should really use scp/sftp. (try paramiko for Python). If you are sure the remote server is running FTP, then use the default port 21.

Comment: hi, though it is getting connected its not accepting the credentials m giving..do i need to make any changes in any files on either the remote machine or in the laocal machine for that.

Comment: so you are using FTP right? if its not accepting the credential then check your password and user name...